# How to use minizinc with node js?

Tags: node.js, minizinc

I'm trying to run a minizinc solver from node js
I found the minizinc-solver library but i do not know how to build the String of my problem ,do you have examples? 
This is my program :

```
var minizincSolver = require("minizinc-solver")
var problem = String('include "globals.mzn";var 1..9:S;var 0..9:E;var 0..9:N;var 0..9:D;var 1..9:M;var 0..9:O;var 0..9:R;var 0..9:Y;constraint 1000_S + 100_E + 10_N + D + 1000_M + 100_O + 10_R + E = 10000_M + 1000_O + 100_N + 10_E + Y;constraint alldifferent([S,E,N,D,M,O,R,Y]);solve satisfy;output [" ",show(S),show(E),show(N),show(D),"\n"," + ",show(M),show(O),show(R),show(E),"\n"," = ",show(M),show(O),show(N),show(E),show(Y),"\n"];');

console.log(problem);
minizincSolver.solve(problem);
```

I have an undefined response while running it
thanks!!

Comment: I am not familiar with the MiniZinc wrapper you are using. Is there any reason to use underscore '_' characters rather than '*' to express multiplication?